# Can this congruence be reduced?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If I have

$$(x+1)^2 \equiv 0 \bmod (y+1)$$

Is this as simple as it gets? I have values for $x$ and wish to solve for valid $y$.

Comment: Are there zero divisors mod (y+1)? For example, mod 4, the solutions would be 1 and 3 mod 4 for x as 0 can be squared but so can 2 in this special case of $y+1=p^2$.

Comment: @JBKing I am not sure what you are asking, but it is possible for there to be no solutions to this congruence depending on the value of $x$ I suppose

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor explains the concept that is worth noting as usually in algebra if $a^2=0$ then $a=0$ is given as a consequence which in this case would mean there is a reduction to $x\equiv-1 mod (y+1)$

Comment: @JBKing Oh, in this case, no I don't think that applies here

Comment: Every $y$ is one less than a divisor of $(x+1)^2$. What else do you want?

Comment: Is $(x+1)^2-1$ really the solution for $y$ or could there be more than that?

Comment: @JBKing Say for example $x = 5$, then $(x+1)^2= 36 = 2^2\cdot 3^2$.  You have $36\equiv 0 (\text{mod} 1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36)$, so $y\in\{0,1,2,3,5,8,11,17,35\}$, i.e. exactly what anon said.  Look at the divisors of $(x+1)^2$.  For each divisor of $(x+1)^2$, if you subtract one, that will be a valid choice for $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$
>
> $$a\equiv 0 (\text{mod} b)~~~\Leftrightarrow~~~b|a~~~\Leftrightarrow ~~~\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}~s.t.~~~a = b\cdot k$$

As $(x+1)^2\equiv 0(\text{mod} ~(y+1))$, it follows that $(y+1)|(x+1)^2$

You may find a list of all such values of $(y+1)$, namely the divisors of $(x+1)^2$, by looking at the prime factorization of $(x+1)^2$.

When $(x+1)^2 = p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}p_3^{r_3}\cdots p_n^{r_n}$ with each $p_i$ a distinct prime, and each $r_i$ a positive integer, every divisor of $(x+1)^2$ will be of the form $p_1^{q_1}p_2^{q_2}p_3^{q_3}\cdots p_n^{q_n}$ with each $q_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\leq q_i\leq r_i$.  For each choice of $q$'s, you will get a different divisor of $(x+1)^2$, and by multiplication principle there are then $(r_1+1)(r_2+1)(r_3+1)\cdots(r_n+1)$ total positive divisors.

For example: $49 = 7^2$ so the divisors are $7^0, 7^1, 7^2$, which simplify to $1,7,49$.  Another example $36 = 2^2\cdot 3^2$ so the divisors are $2^0\cdot 3^0, 2^1\cdot 3^0, 2^2\cdot 3^0, 2^0\cdot 3^1, 2^1\cdot 3^1, \dots, 2^2\cdot 3^2$, which simplify to $1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36$.

Whenever $y+1$ is a divisor of $(x+1)^2$, then $(x+1)^2\equiv 0(\text{mod}~y+1)$ and so any $y$ such that $y$ is one less than a divisor of $(x+1)^2$ will suffice.